# rake db:migrate fail ~> PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, dbmigrate

Hi can someone help me with the error i a getting when i try to do the

```
rake db:migrate
```

using ubuntu 14

this is the error that follows

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

any helm will do , as i am trying to update the database , just did a fresh clone and bundle install into my directory to try it out and this is what it shows when i try doing the

```
rake db:migrate
```

i dont know why but anyhelp will do and thanks